# Sending header with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, header

I have an API and Frontend service. I want to send some header with every request to get access to the API.

Here's the code. I'm using cURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "backend_service.com/api/$url");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       "XAUTH_KEY: ".env('XAUTH_KEY')
   ));

$server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

The question is: Why I can't get access to this header via Request.

This code is working:

```
if ($auth_key == getallheaders()['XAUTH_KEY']) {
    return $next($request);
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
if ($request->header('XAUTH_KEY')) {
    return $next($request);
}
```

Similar problem with Ajax requests. Header doesn't sends correctly, but in this case I can't receive it even with `getallheaders()`

Here output in browser:

```
Accept:*/* 
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 
Access-Control-Request-Headers:xauth_key 
Access-Control-Request-Method:DELETE 
Connection:keep-alive 
Host:backend_service.com 
Origin:frontend_service.com 
Referer:frontend_service.com/… 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can u please clarify "this doesn't work"? What does it do? Any errormessages?

Comment: You could try `hasHeader` instead https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_hasHeader

Comment: @FabianSchöner it's hard to debug. When I make request from Frontend I just see "response null" or smth like that. I tried dump and die it on API side, but response still null.